# Can't compile shader without glfw context

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt, shader, pyopengl

I am trying to compile OpenGL shaders using the Python bindings. I can not compile them without creating a glfw context, it is quite strange. If you uncomment the glfw lines, the shaders will get compiled.
print(bool(glCreateShader)) outputs False.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\latebind.py", line 43, in __call__
    return self._finalCall( *args, **named )
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/reas/Desktop/Programación/OpenGeEle/Moderno.py", line 44, in <module>
    shader = compileShader(vertex_src, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GL\shaders.py", line 228, in compileShader
    shader = glCreateShader(shaderType)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\latebind.py", line 46, in __call__
    self._finalCall = self.finalise()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\extensions.py", line 242, in finalise
    raise error.NullFunctionError(
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined alternate function (glCreateShader, glCreateShaderObjectARB), check for bool(glCreateShader) before calling

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Source code:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from OpenGL.GL import (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, GL_STATIC_DRAW,
                       GL_VERTEX_SHADER, glBindBuffer, glBufferData, glClear, glClearColor,
                       glGenBuffers)
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileShader, compileProgram
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QOpenGLWidget

# IF I UNCOMMENT THIS, THE SHADERS WORK
"""
import glfw

glfw.init()
window = glfw.create_window(1280, 720, "My OpenGL window", None, None)
glfw.make_context_current(window)
"""

vertex_src = """
# version 330

in vec3 a_position;
in vec3 a_color;

out vec3 v_color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    v_color = a_color;
}
"""

fragment_src = """
# version 330

in vec3 v_color;
out vec4 out_color;

void main()
{
    out_color = vec4(v_color, 1.0);
}
"""

shader = compileShader(vertex_src, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
shader2 = compileShader(fragment_src, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
programa = compileProgram(shader, shader2)
```

Comment: @genpfault how can I create it without glfw? I want to use PyQt5

Comment: Qt provides an OpenGL context, in a `QGLWidget`, but context is only current in the  `initializeGL`, `paintGL` and `resizeGL` callback

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, If I put the compiling instructions inside the paintGL method it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any OpenGL instruction a current and valid [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) is required. [`QOpenGLWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QOpenGLWidget.html) creates and provides an OpenGL context, but the context is only made current before the `initializeGL`, `paintGL` respectively `resizeGL` callback.
Hence you have to move the code, which creates and compiles the shader, in the `initializeGL` event callback method.

Comment: *In order for any OpenGL commands to work, a context must be current; all OpenGL commands affect the state of whichever context is current.*